# bash create file in directory, only part of directory name is known

Tags: bash, automation, directory, glob

I have a bunch of directories named using the convention *prefix.suffix*. *prefix* is numeric and *suffix* is alphanumeric of any length.
`mkdir 123.abcdef`

*prefix* is always unique but I don't always know what *suffix* is at `bash` script runtime.
Within my script, how can I have `bash` write to a given directory by knowing only the *prefix*?
The following doesn't work but I tried:
`echo "itworks" > 123*/results.text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob the directory part to loop on the globs:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for dir in 123*/; do
    echo "itworks" > "${dir}results.text"
done
```

You can also enforce checking that there's a unique directory matching:

```
shopt -s nullglob

dirs=( 123*/ )
if (( ${#dirs[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo >&2 "No dirs found!"
    exit 1
elif (( ${#dirs[@]} > 1 )); then
    echo >&2 "More than one dir found!"
    exit 1
fi

# Here you're good
echo "itworks" > "${dirs[0]}results.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could force evaluation of the directory name with wildcards using 'ls -d'

```
echo "itworks" > $(ls -d 123*)/results.txt
```

Comment: `ls` is really useless for this task. `echo "itworks" > "$(printf '%s' 123*/)results.txt"` would be slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix='yourprefix' && find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "$prefix*" \
-exec echo "Hello" {}/results.txt \;
```

should do it.